# Create "Add Interface" button for Visual Studio C# Menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interface, add-on

I'd like to add an "Add Interface" button to Visual Studio's "Add New Item" menu. It would be similar to the one-click "Add Class" button, but for interfaces. Is this possible? I've attached a screenshot with the menu I want to add it to.[image]

Comment: Have you looked up anything about Visual Studio extensions? Have you tried anything? Is there already an extension that does this?

Comment: This is where you want to start... [Starting to Develop Visual Studio Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is definitely what I was looking for. I did search around a bit but had no idea what to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions of Joe and Quaabaam I was able to make my own extension that does this. Here's the link if anyone else had this issue and wants the extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Thomas-Margraff.AddNewInterface

[image]

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.