# How to use shortcut Project.AddInterface?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I added a shortcut for `Project.AddInterface`:
[image]

Now, when pressing this key combination, the Visual Studio "bottom bar" shows this error:
[image]

I can't see what I am doing wrong. My goal is to have a shortcut for adding an interface like one can add a class with `Ctrl+N,Ctrl+C`. How to reach my goal? I am using Visual Studio 17.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue.

[image]

[image]

and found:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-interface-shortcut-and-command-menu-not-workin/782614?viewtype=solutions

But this does not seem to attract the attention of the Visual Studio development team. You can report your issue on [this website](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home) and put the link you posted in developercommunity into this SO post so that it can help more people.

In addition, before fixing this issue, you can seek some alternatives:

1. Add the AddClass shortcut key so that you can find the Interface option in the pop-up menu
2. [Create "Add Interface" button for Visual Studio C# Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68595799/create-add-interface-button-for-visual-studio-c-sharp-menu)